# Understanding, Recursion in Ruby

Tags: ruby, recursion, factorial

In recursion, a method calls itself. I'm not following it when there are return values. For example, in the "Learn to Program" book by Chris Pine, there is this example on factorials.

```
def factorial num 
  if num < 0
    return 'You cant\'t take the factorial of a negative number!'
  end
  if num <= 1
    1
  else 
    num * factorial(num-1)
  end
end
```

If I call the method `factorial(3)`, it will go to the `else` portion of the code and will look like this:

```
3 * factorial(3-1)
```

and should return `6` since `3*2=6`. `factorial(3-1)` calls the `factorial` method passing `2` within the recursion. `num = 2`, and thus `2 * factorial(2-1)` and `2*1=2`.

What happens to the `6` that we got from our first run through the code? Now that `num = 1`, it looks like this will now return `1` and go to the end of the code. But from my understanding, we still have `6` and `2` from the previous recursions. Am I correct in this assumption, since we called the factorial function when we multiplied by `num`? Can someone help me understand this better? Say we called `factorial(10)`, how would this work out?

Comment: Did you watch Inception ?

Comment: All that code... when all you had to do is: `def fact(n) (1..n).inject(1) {|r,i| r*i } end`  :)

Comment: The factorial function is always used as an example for recursion when it's a *terrible* way to solve that problem. I think this has inflicted all kinds of brain-damage on beginning programmers, as soon every problem becomes something to be solved with recursion instead of a proper technique like a stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should replace your `return 'blabla'` with a `raise 'blabla'` because your function returns a numeric, not a string.

Then see it like this

```
factorial(3)
  3 * factorial(2)
        2 * factorial(1)
              1  # no more recursion, let's go up replacing 
                 # the function calls by the returned value
            end
      end
end
# ↓
factorial(3)
  3 * factorial(2)
        2 * 1  # let's go up again !
      end
end
# ↓
factorial(3)
  3 * 2 # finally
end
# ↓
6
```

Answer (score 4):

> Now what happens to the 6 that we got from our first run through the
>   code?

There was no 6 from the first run; the 6 only appeared at the end.

This is what happens:

```
factorial(3) → 3 * factorial(2)
factorial(3) → 3 * 2 * factorial(1)
factorial(3) → 3 * 2 * 1
```

There is no “memory” of previous calls in your function, each time factorial() is called, it's like a brand new function; is it clearer when written as multiple functions?

```
def factorialof3
  3 * factorialof2
end

def factorialof2
  2 * factorialof1
end

def factorialof1
  1
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Patrice answer splitting it up into separate functions is good, and if you have any background in computer science, it will also help to think of what data structures are probably at work here, mainly the [Stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29)

So when you call `factorial(3)` it will go to that `else` block and 'stack' on another call to factorial(2)

and then stack another one with a call to `factorial(1)`.

at that point, since `num = 1`, (recursion must always have a base case) factorial(1) will return 1.

Then because of the stack, the last one in is the first one out, so the factorial(1) will return 1, and that will 'fall' back down to the `factorial(2)` call, and because it was called in that else block, the call to `factorial(2-1)` will now be replaced by 1, and you will get 2*1, and I think by now you get the picture

It is also important to note, this example is trying to teach you recursion in general, and this example is not really idiomatic ruby. The solution alfasin posted as a comment is more like it.